# span & div tags not replacing outer p tags of selection in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE Editor and I'm trying to edit the [style_formats](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/user-formatting-options/#style_formats). I added my own headings:

```
//...
{ title: 'Headings', items: [
                { title: 'Titre principal', block: 'div', classes: ['title'], wrapper: true },
                { title: 'Titre alternatif', block: 'div', classes: ['title-alt'], wrapper: true },
                { title: 'Titre alternatif (gris)', block: 'div', classes: ['title-alt', 'grey'], wrapper: true },
                { title: 'Titre informatif', block: 'div', classes: ['title-alt', 'infos'], wrapper: true },
                { title: 'Sous-titre', block: 'div', classes: 'subtitle', wrapper: true },
                { title: 'Petit titre', block: 'div', styles: { color: 'var(--violet)', fontFamily: 'var(--playfair)', fontWeight: 'bold' }, wrapper: true }
]},
//...
```

But it's not working like intended. When I click on them, it does this:

```html
<div class="title">
<p>
Text goes here
</p>
</div>
```

Which isn't what I'm expecting. I'm expecting this output:

```html
<div class="title">
Text goes here
</div>
```

Without the p tags.

It worked well before, with the headings that comes with tinyMCE, which are h1, h2, h3,... Is there an additional option I'm missing in my items?

Also, I tried things like:

```
valid_children : '-div[p]'
```

But it just doesn't work at all: when I click on one of the headings, it just does nothing. I can't add any div with this filter.

I also tried to specify a custom [format](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-formatting/#formats) for those titles, but when I click on them, they just replace every div before them. Like, if I have this:

```html
<div class="cadre-admin">
<p>
Text goes here
</p>
</div>
```

It becomes this when I select a title:

```html
<div class="title">
Text goes here
</div>
```

Can someone help, please?

I added a [fiddle](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/I5iaab) with the one they provide at tinyMCE.

Comment: It would make the question better if you would include the sample code as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), in the question itself, rather than just on the fiddle site...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I already tried to make it into a Stack Snippet and I couldn't make it work, so I did a fiddle with the tinyMCE fiddle editor.